# Laravel 5.8 pluck a relationship and use a local scope for that relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

This seems pretty straightforward, but haven't had any luck. I have one to many `Task` to `Block` relationship. The relationships: 
`Task->blocks`:

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Block::class, 'task_uuid', 'task_uuid');
}
```

`Blocks->task`:

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class, 'task_uuid', 'task_uuid');
}
```

With that I can get all of a task's blocks like so: `$task->blocks;`. I'm trying to pluck all plucks from a collection of tasks: `$tasks->pluck('blocks')` and use a local scope that is on the `Block` model:

```
public function scopeUnresolved($query)
{
    return $query->where('resolved_at', null);
}
```

Some of my attempts (even the super dumb ones):
`$tasks->pluck('blocks')->unresolved()->get();`
`$tasks->pluck('blocks')->flatten()->unresolved()->get();`
`$tasks->pluck('blocks')->filter()->get()->unresolved()->get();`
and a few others as well. I've gotten this to work:

```
$tasks->pluck('blocks')->flatten()->filter(function ($block) {
    return $block->unresolved()->get();
});
```

It seems like there'd be a more concise way to go about it, but perhaps not? Any insights on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done when querying for your `$tasks`; if you wait til after you've already pulled your `Task` models, you'll likely have to do it in a loop, which is an n+1 issue. Try using "Eager Loading":

```
$tasks = Task::with(["blocks" => function($subQuery){
  $subQuery->whereNull("resolved_at");
  // or, if you want to use your `scopeUnresolved()`
  $subQuery->unresolved();
}])->get();
```

Note: `where("unresolved_at", null)` may or may not work, but there is a `whereNull()` method

Now, when you try to access a task's blocks, it'll only contain those that are unresolved:

```
foreach($tasks AS $task){
  dd($task->blocks);
  // etc.
}
```